# android layer-list header and footer

Tags: android, header, background, gradient, footer

I am trying to create a background drawable for a linearlayout that has multiple gradients.

E.g. I want to have a gradient at the top and bottom, and a solid color in the middle. So basically a header and footer.

I am trying to use a layer-list like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <!--Red-->
 <item>
  <shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid
    android:color="#ff0000" />
  </shape>

 </item>
 <!-- Green -->
        <!-- Offsets from the top and bottom -->
 <item
  android:top="20dp"
  android:bottom="20dp">
  <shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid
    android:color="#00ff00" />
  </shape>

 </item>
 <item
  android:top="80dp">
  <!--Blue -->
  <shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid
    android:color="#0000ff" />
  </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is, I am unsure of the max value of density independant pixels. For this to work, the bottom item offest would need to be (max dp value-20). I have tried to assume the max is 100, and also assume the max is 160 (from the documentation), but neither of these work.

Any ideas?